# Label to report percentage of recurrent/new authors in conference submissions

Tags: conference, paper-submission, statistics

We would like to report some stats on the submissions for a specific conference, but we are unsure whether similar statistics have been reported elsewhere, and if we should consequently adopt an existing label.

More specifically, we are interested in reporting the (i) % of submissions with all authors being recurrent; (ii) % of submissions with at least one recurring and one new author; (iii) % of submissions with all new authors. Recurrent authors denote those who have submitted to the conference for > 1 year. The idea is to learn e.g. whether recurrent authors have brought new ones to the conference.

I've been looking into reports of the CHI and AAAI conference series but found nothing related. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you need to obsess over this.

Comment: If you don't like "new" then maybe "first-time authors" would work? I've seen a number of conferences provide guidance to "first-time attendees".

Comment: @Anyon Perhaps "submitters"? "First-time author" would imply it's their first conference poster, which is usually not the case.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim I guess it could be specified further, e.g. "First-time FC paper author", where FC=Fancy Conference. "Submitter" seems awkward to me, since I'd interpret submitter to be the person actually submitting the paper (so each paper has exactly one submitter, but potentially multiple authors). Maybe the interpretation would be field-dependent though.

Comment: @Anyon Fair point. I think "new FC authors" works fine

Comment: Thanks - good points indeed! @Buffy: I won't worry too much, but I don't want to overlook the obvious.